# Classic ASP looping through array

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I think I'm very close, but it's just not there yet. 
I'm generating a recordset, then assigning variables and constructing an e-mail with those variables, sending the e-mail and then moving to the next record and doing it again until they're all done.
My problem is that in my example code, it does send four (4) e-mails, but all of them are the first record, so it's not moving to the next one.
Here's my example code:

```
set rs_remailer = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    sql="SELECT contact.ID, contact.contacttypeID, contact.firstname, contact.lastname, contact.email, contact.company, contact.phone, contact.street, contact.location, contact.cityID, contact.postal, contact.comments, contact.email_alert, contact.created_date, cities.ID AS citiesID, cities.countryID, cities.displayname AS citiesdisplayname, contacttype.displayname AS contacttypedisplayname FROM contact INNER JOIN cities ON cities.ID = contact.cityID INNER JOIN contacttype ON contacttype.ID = contact.contacttypeID  WHERE (contact.ID BETWEEN 5753 AND 5757) ORDER BY contact.ID ASC;"
    rs_remailer.Open sql, conn
    remailerTotalRecords = rs_remailer.getRows()

    Dim contact_ID()
    Dim contact_createddate()
    Dim contact_contacttypedisplayname()
    Dim contact_firstname()
    Dim contact_lastname()
    Dim contact_email()
    Dim contact_company()
    Dim contact_phone()
    Dim contact_street()
    Dim contact_location()
    Dim contact_postal()
    Dim contact_comments()
    Dim contact_emailalert()
    Dim contact_citiesdisplayname()

    contactNumber = 0

    while not rs_remailer.eof
        ReDim Preserve contact_ID(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_createddate(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_contacttypedisplayname(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_firstname(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_lastname(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_email(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_company(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_phone(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_street(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_location(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_postal(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_comments(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_emailalert(contactNumber+1)
        ReDim Preserve contact_citiesdisplayname(contactNumber+1)

        contact_ID(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("ID")
        contact_createddate(contactNumber) = FormatDateTime(rs_remailer("created_date"),1)
        contact_contacttypedisplayname(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("contacttypedisplayname")
        contact_firstname(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("firstname")
        contact_lastname(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("lastname")
        contact_email(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("email")
        contact_company(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("company")
        contact_phone(contactNumber) = formatphone(rs_remailer("phone"))
        contact_street(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("street")
        contact_location(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("location")
        contact_postal(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("postal")
        contact_comments(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("comments")
        contact_emailalert(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("email_alert")
        contact_citiesdisplayname(contactNumber) = rs_remailer("citiesdisplayname")



            emailcontent = ""

            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<h2>" & contact_contacttypedisplayname(i) & " Form Submission</h2>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<p>This message was originally sent on: " & contact_createddate(i) & " </p>"


            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<p>The following Form Submission was made on the ADS-Pipe website:</p>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<tr>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='right' valign='top' nowrap='nowrap'><b>User:</b></td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td width='6' align='left' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='left' valign='top'>" & contact_firstname(i) & " " & contact_lastname(i) & "</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "</tr>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<tr>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='right' valign='top' nowrap='nowrap'><b>E-mail:</b></td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td width='6' align='left' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='left' valign='top'><a href='mailto:" & contact_email(i) & "'>" & contact_email(i) & "</a></td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "</tr>"
        if not isblank(contact_company(i)) then
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<tr>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='right' valign='top' nowrap='nowrap'><b>Company:</b></td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td width='6' align='left' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='left' valign='top'>" & contact_company(i) & "</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "</tr>"
        end if
        if not isblank(contact_phone(i)) then
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<tr>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='right' valign='top' nowrap='nowrap'><b>Phone:</b></td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td width='6' align='left' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='left' valign='top'>" & contact_phone(i) & "</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "</tr>"
        end if
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<tr>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='right' valign='top' nowrap='nowrap'><b>Address:</b></td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td width='6' align='left' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='left' valign='top'>"
            if NOT isblank(contact_street(i)) then emailcontent = emailcontent & contact_street(i) & "<br />"
            if NOT isblank(contact_location(i)) then emailcontent = emailcontent & contact_location(i) & "<br />"
            if NOT isblank(contact_postal(i)) then emailcontent = emailcontent & contact_postal(i)
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "</tr>"
        if NOT isblank(contact_comments(i)) then
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<tr>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='right' valign='top' nowrap='nowrap'><b>Comments:</b></td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td width='6' align='left' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='left' valign='top'>" & contact_comments(i) & "</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "</tr>"
        end if
        if contact_emailalert(i) then
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<tr>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='right' valign='top' nowrap='nowrap'><b>E-mail Alerts:</b></td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='left' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<td align='left' valign='top'>The customer has indicated that they would like to receive e-mail updates about ADS technical information and products.</td>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "</tr>"
        end if




            emailcontent = emailcontent & "</table>"
            emailcontent = emailcontent & "<br />"



    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'CLOSE THE DATABASE
            'rs_contactFormDisplayname.close
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------

            'send email notification
            dim Mailer
            set Mailer = server.createobject("CDO.Message") 

            location_parts = Split(contact_location(i), ",")

            suffix = " "
            if UBound(location_parts) = 2 then suffix = " (" & trim(location_parts(2)) & ")"

            email_subject = "[Website] " & contact_contacttypedisplayname(i) & " Form Submission" & suffix

            Mailer.From = ""

            Mailer.HtmlBody = "<html><body>" & emailcontent & "</body></html>"
            Mailer.Subject = email_subject
            with Mailer.Configuration
                .Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
                .Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = mailserver
                .Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
                .Fields.Update
            end with
            Mailer.Send
            set Mailer = Nothing
            CDOSYS_Mailer = true

        contactNumber = contactNumber + 1
        rs_remailer.movenext
    wend


    remailerTotalRecords = rs_remailer.RecordCount

    rs_remailer.close


            response.end
```

I think I'm just not getting where to make the record move up so the next one gets used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're reading your arrays, you're using index variable `i`, which is never incremented.

Example:

```
emailcontent = emailcontent & "<h2>" & contact_contacttypedisplayname(i) & " Form Submission</h2>"
'NEVER INCREMENTED ---------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you're using the getRows() method, you don't really have to have declare so many arrays. You can simply loop through the method with something from this example: http://www.aspfaqs.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=161